# Cannot draw on the Oz dimension (Tried OSNAP)

Tags: autocad

I'm a beginner learning to draw with Autocad 2018. But drawing a house, I can't draw a door, a rectangle going up in Oz dimension. It's only allowed to draw in Oxy.

I tried turn on and off OSNAP (F3) but it did not work out.

Also I can't just draw a rectangle that starts from a line, it needs to be 2 lines.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is Oz dimension?  Do you men you cant draw in the Z dimension and can only draw 2 dimensionly in the XY plane?

Comment: @ForwardEd thanks for your help. Yes, I meant to draw in Z dimension. It's a real house, so things are in 3D. But I figured it out myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: another option is to changer your view to ISOMETRIC

Answer (score 0):

I figured out:
You have to activate an option named "3d object snap". It's in the menu bar (bottom, farest to the right).